# Extensions of swift classes and structs behave differently

Tags: swift

The problem is that I have some struct or class with generic constraint that conforms to some protocol. When I try to add specialized implementation depending on type of generic type T it works for classes but does not work for structs. I can not use class in my specific use case cause this class should conform to protocol that requires initializer, but I can not specify class initializer in extension.

Any way to make it work? Or should I choose another path? Here is a code snippet demonstrating a problem.

```
protocol ProtocolA {}
protocol ProtocolB: ProtocolA {}
protocol ProtocolC {
    fun act()
}

struct StructA: ProtocolA {}

struct StructB: ProtocolB {}

struct StructC<T: ProtocolA>: ProtocolC {}

extension StructC {
    func act() {
        print("general")
    }
}

extension StructC where T: ProtocolB {
    func act() {
        print("special")
    }
}

class ClassC<T: ProtocolA>: ProtocolC {
}

extension ClassC {
    func act() {
        print("general")
    }
}

extension ClassC where T: ProtocolB {
    func act() {
        print("special")
    }
}

let classCA = ClassC<StructA>()
let classCB = ClassC<StructB>()

//this works
classCA.act() //-> "general"
classCB.act() //-> "special"

let structCA = StructC<StructA>()
let structCB = StructC<StructB>()

//Does not even compile
structCA.act() 
structCB.act() // error: "Ambigous use of 'act()'"
```

UPD: If I use protocol with type alias and extend protocol instead of struct then it works:

```
protocol ProtocolD {
    typealias V
    func act()
}

struct StructD<T: ProtocolA>: ProtocolD {
    typealias V = T
}

extension ProtocolD {
    func act() {
        print("general")
    }
}

extension ProtocolD where V: ProtocolB {
    func act() {
        print("special")
    }
}

let structDA = StructD<StructA>()
let structDB = StructD<StructB>()

//works again
structDA.act() //-> "general"
structDB.act() //-> "special"
```

But it still does not solve or explain the issue of different behaviour for classes and struct.

UPD:Filed radar for that issue rdar://23314307

Answer (score 0):

From first sight you declare here

```
`let structCB = StructC<StructB>()`
```

But implement extension with ProtocolB, when StructB only inherits this protocol:

```
extension StructC where T: ProtocolB {
    func act() {
        print("special")
    }
}
```

`StructB` inherits `ProtocolB`, but `ProtocolB` doesn't "inherit" `StructB`.
If you make default implementation for this extension it will work:

```
extension StructC where T: StructB {
    func act() {
        print("special")
    }
}
```

UPD:

At last I understood your question and became intrested too - why it doesn't work.
The problem is `protocol ProtocolB: ProtocolA {}`
And then in generic `ProtocolB` is not treated like inheritance from `ProtocolA`. I think you can change a little bit your logic and solve the problem:

Your `ProtocolB` expands `ProtocolA` whith adding some functions for example. You can add functions in `StructB` if is acceptable

Comment: As I understand it when I specify constraint on type `T` in extension I say that this extension should be applied for any type of T that conforms to this  constraint. So `StructB` conforms to `T: ProtocolB`, 'cause it conforms to `ProtocolB` so it should get implementation from this extension. Is that wrong? Also in my actual use case I can not use concrete class in extension like you suggest.

Comment: can you explain in more details what is your suggestion? `ProtocolB` is there exactly for what you say - to add some functionality on top of `ProtocolA`. It just does not matter for illustration. If I add some functions in `StructB` without adding them to `ProtocolB` I will not be able to access them in extension, cause `T` is `ProtocolB`, not `StructB`. I hope it's not too much confusing with all these A and B...

Comment: I also tried not to inherit `ProtocolB` from `ProtocolA`, but to conform to them separately in `StructB` like : `struct StructB: ProtocolA, ProtocolB {}`, but it still has ambiguity error.

Answer (score -1):

You missed out `mutating`:

```
extension StructC where T: ProtocolB {
    mutating func act() {
        print("special")
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pravan - not every method on struct should be marked as 'mutating' and it does not have to do anything with described issue.

Comment: @Pravan - more than that adding 'mutating' breaks conformance of `StructC` to protocol `ProtocolC` if you don't add `mutating` to protocol itself.

Comment: @IlyaPuchka Of course not every method has to be marked `mutating` but,  in this case, your extension is changing `self` so it does. If you make the change and run your sample code you will see that it compiles. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

Comment: @Pravan - What aspect of `StructC` method 'act' changes? It does not compile.

Comment: @Pranav You should include *in your answer* the explanation of why you're proposing this solution.